# Can't connect Redux store to React Typescript App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to connect Redux Store to my TypeScript-React app, but receiving the following error:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props:
>   Readonly>): Provider', gave the
>   following error. Type '() => any' is missing the following properties
>   from type 'Store': dispatch, getState, subscribe,
>   replaceReducer, [Symbol.observable]   Overload 2 of 2, '(props:
>   ProviderProps, context?: any): Provider', gave
>   the following error.
>       Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'Store'.ts(2769) index.d.ts(461, 5): The expected type comes from
>   property 'store' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes> &
>   Readonly> & Readonly<...>' index.d.ts(461,
>   5): The expected type comes from property 'store' which is declared
>   here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes> &
>   Readonly> & Readonly<...>'

here is my **index.tsx** component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import store from './store/index';

import './styles/index.scss';

import LoginPage from './app/routes/LoginPage';

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and my store:

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

export default configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(countReducer);
  return store;
};
```

**reducer.js**:

```
const countReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Should I specify the type of a store somewhere?

Comment: From where you are getting this `countReducer` under `store.js` ?

Comment: You have to pass the reducer or combined reducer under `createStore()`, in your case you are passing it but haven't imported it may be this is the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You exported `store` as a function, but using it like a variable. Don't forget to invoke the function.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
    import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import store from './store/index'; // store is a function
    import './styles/index.scss';   
    import LoginPage from './app/routes/LoginPage';

    const App = () => (
      <Provider store={store()}> // <- Call the function here
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Provider>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```